# Image Sprites Within Link Element

Tags: html, css, css-sprites

Pardon me if I am not able to be clear about what I am attempting to do. I've done simpler variations of what I am about to explain, but not like this.

I have this grid of link elements that I am creating for a "dashboard". The intent is to have a 64x64 icon thats a visual representation of the Title and Description that will be placed to the right of the icon. The entire element (icon, title, and description) need to be one link so the user has the best possible chance of clicking on the element they desire, and as such I need to apply CSS formatting to the link and icon based on the action of the link.

For example, during normal operation (and for all "visted" links) there will be a normal looking icon and mostly uncolored text to accompany it. When the user hovers over the element, the icon will switch to a different version (likely lighter) and the text switches to an alternate color. When the user clicks on the element, the icon will again switch to a different version, as will the text. The trick is that the icon image is to be one image wherein the CSS switches it's display of the icon.

The stumbling point for me is as such: If I dont set a height for the cell block, the text height (or the amount of text present for that element) distates the height of the cell and thus affects how the icon is displayed. Here is a screenshot of the issue:

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6y09.png](http://i43.tinypic.com/1toefl.png)

If someone could assist me in creating a cell block wherein the icon displays just the section of the image necessary for that link state AND allow for any amount of tex tto be displayed without adversely affecting the displayed icon, that'd be awesome. I can provide source HTML upon request.

---

UPDATE:

Source Code--
This is the HTML used within the table. All cells follow this general template:

```
<td width="25%">
<a href="#" id="linkPLP_AccandAcc" runat="server" class="PLP_AccandAcc secondaryColor">
    <div class="spacer">
    <h2>
        <span id="lblPLP_AccandAcc" runat="server"></span>
            Accounts and Access 
           </h2>
       <span class="description" id="lblPLP_AccandAccDescription" runat="server"></span>
        Categories: User Account, Password, Network access, Wi-Fi, VPN, IFS Security/Permissions and Sharepoint
    </div>
</a>
</td>
```

And here's the general CSS code used for all the icons:

```
a.PLP_AccandAcc
{
    float:left; position:relative;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    background-image:url(../hsimages/NE/newService-sprite.png);
    background-position:0px 0px; 
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
a.PLP_AccandAcc:visited
{
    float:left; position:relative;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    background-image:url(../hsimages/NE/newService-sprite.png);
    background-position:0px 0px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
a.PLP_AccandAcc:hover
{
    float:left; position:relative;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    background-image:url(../hsimages/NE/newService-sprite.png);
    background-position:0px -105px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
a.PLP_AccandAcc:active
{
    float:left; position:relative;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    background-image:url(../hsimages/NE/newService-sprite.png);
    background-position:0px -210px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: I request source HTML.

Comment: Yeah, that should be pretty easy to do, but it would be useful to have your HTML, CSS and image(s). I would use a single background sprite image for the icons, but space them far apart in the sprite image so that the different states don't show if the box gets large.

Comment: @ralph.m  I've updated the question with example code. Hopefully this shows how it's set up now. Making the images bigger does make more sense, but it doesnt solve the problem wherein the image isnt fully displayed if the text isnt long enough to meet a minimum height.

Comment: Putting your code into a file doesn't reveal much, but if that's the only issue, I would suggest you just set a min-height on the box which is big enough for the icon to show. If the content is taller than the icon, of course the box will grow taller, but it won't be able to get shorter than the icon.

Comment: @ralph.m makes sense. In the event the cell height needs to be taller than the min height, what do you suggest so as to avoid the CSS revealing the next "sprite" of the image inadvertently? Would it be smarter to design the sprite to be horizontal instead of vertical so that the height is no longer a factor?

Comment: Any input here would be greatly appreciated!